# Swagger Codegen - Unexpected missing property for name response

Tags: node.js, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate node.js-server stub using codegen. I have downloaded the `swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar` file and am trying to generate the code using cli command. 
However, it is failing with the following error message:

```
[main] ERROR io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - unexpected missing property for name response
[main] WARN io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - skipping invalid array property {
  "baseName" : "response",
  "getter" : "getResponse",
   ....
  "isReadOnly" : false,
  "vendorExtensions" : { },
  "hasValidation" : false,
  "isXmlAttribute" : false,
  "isXmlWrapped" : false
}
[main] ERROR io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - unexpected missing property for name response
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not process operation:
  Tag: Tag {
        name: messages
        description: Messages for blue instance
        externalDocs: null
        extensions:{}}
  Operation: listMessages
  Resource: get /instances/{instanceId}/messages
  Definitions: {message-common=io.swagger.models.ModelImpl@e68ed4e0, Error Response=io.swagger.models.ModelImpl@7bcf5e6c}
  Exception: null
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processOperation(DefaultGenerator.java:932)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processPaths(DefaultGenerator.java:808)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateApis(DefaultGenerator.java:431)
        at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:746)
        at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:285)
        at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        ... 5 more
```

Here is an excerpt from my swagger definitions file. 
I did adding/removing `x-swagger-router-controller` attribute, but that did not help either.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Messages API
  version: '1.0'
  description: |-
    Call used to get messages
host: 'localhost:8080'
paths:
  '/instances/{instanceId}/messages':
    get:
      summary: Get all messages
      operationId: listMessages
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'Success Response'
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              title: Message Output
              description: The properties that are included
              allOf:
                - type: object
                  properties:
                    id:
                      type: string
                - title: Message Common
                  description: The properties that are shared
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    message:
                      type: string
                      description: Operation the system must do
                    details:
                      type: string
                      description: 'Textual data'
                  required:
                    - message
                    - details
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized requests
          schema:
            type: object
            title:  Error Response
            description: Standard  error message.
            properties:
              errors:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    code:
                      type: string
                      description: Human readable category
                    message:
                      type: string
                      description: Detailed error message
                  required:
                    - code
                    - message
            required:
              - errors
        '500':
          description: Response for other issues
          schema:
            type: object
            title:  Error Response
            description: Standard  error message.
            properties:
              errors:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    code:
                      type: string
                      description: Human readable category
                    message:
                      type: string
                      description: Detailed error message
                  required:
                    - code
                    - message
            required:
              - errors
      description: 'Call used to get messages, notices, and/or instructions from E&E system for the product to take. '
      parameters:
        - name: Digest
          in: header
          type: string
          description: The digest for the body being passed
      tags:
        - messages
    parameters:
      - name: instanceId
        in: path
        type: string
        required: true
        description: The specific instance for which the message is relevant
basePath: /v1
schemes:
  - http
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
tags:
  - name: messages
    description: Messages for instance
```

Please help. Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is caused by inline models in `responses`. While this is perfectly valid, it might be that Swagger Codegen does not support this. You can open an issue in the [Swagger Codegen repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues).

Try putting the model definitions in the global `definitions` section, so that your `responses` section looks like this:

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'Success Response'
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Message'
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized requests
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
        '500':
          description: Response for other issues
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
```